# Python 3 Selenium Button find_element_by_

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to click button on a website, but the problem is there are many exactly same buttons and whatever I tried with find_element_by_ so far, nothing worked, browser just closed.

The problem is that I can't use id, because every time the page is refreshed, id is randomly generated.

How would I go and click only first button of many buttons like this.
And how would I go and click only second button of many buttons like this.

I saw something with for loop, but couldn't figure that out either.

Button code:

```
<button type="submit" value="Začni rop" id="button5925d8ad338af" class="green ">
        <div class="button-content">Začni rop</div>
</button>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is always a way to find the desired button "by text":

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[div = 'Začni rop']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@value = 'Začni rop']")
```

And, if you still want to rely on the order of the buttons, you can find them all and get the desired one "by index":

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
buttons[0].click()
```

Comment: Used this and it works

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@value = 'Začni rop']")
buttons[0].click()

Thanks for help